# Bootstrap Modal visible on document load

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a Bootstrap Model working fine, except that it is visible when the document loads and I can't work out how to make the initial state invisible?

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>


<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Following documentation, add `hide` class to the modal.

```
<div class="modal hide fade">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: The _hide_ class is not needed anymore.

Comment: @ThEBiShOp do you know from which version it is not needed anymore? An update to the answer would be great.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out simply adding `style="display: none"` to the modal outer div did the trick.